# How to show setting flyout by using button instead of setting charms

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, flyout, callisto

By using `Callisto` I wrote a code that adds setting charms.

Underneath I attach one:

```
// Register handler for CommandsRequested events from the setting pane
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;

void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    // Add an Adding Feeds command
    var add = new SettingsCommand("add", "Add new Feed", (handler) =>
    {
        var settings = new SettingsFlyout();
        settings.Content = new AddingPageUserControl();
        settings.HeaderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["UserControlBackgraund"];
        settings.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["UserControlBackgraund"];
        settings.HeaderText = "Add new Feed";
        settings.IsOpen = true;
    });

    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(add);
}
```

And I don't know how to create a button in `AppBar` which opens the same setting flyout as I use to open it by setting charms. My question is: is it possible to create it if yes I need a sort of hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `AppBar` using `Page.BottomAppBar` and use `FindName` method to find a specific button and add a handler to that. 
The only point is you are currently creating your `SettingFlyout` inside an anonymous function, so only place you can do that would be inside your anonymous function.